# SwiftUI Padding on iPhone 7 vs iPhone 14

Tags: iphone, swiftui, padding

I am building a relatively simple flash card app using SwiftUI. I have A vertical stack with zStacks and hStacks inside it. I think I have the padding applied correctly, but one oddity that is plaguing me is that when I run the app on the simulator's iPhone 14 it looks like it is supposed to:

[image]

However, when I run it on my own device, which is an iPhone 7, the padding is not applied to the trailing and leading edges (left and right) of the view, but vertically, it seems to apply the padding:

[image]

The padding is applied here in the code:

```
  var body: some View {
ZStack {
  Color("MyGray")
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
  VStack {
    
    ZStack {
      topCard
      bottomCard
    }.padding(10)
    
    VStack {
      ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
        Picker(selection: $selectedTopic, label: Text(topicPickerLabel)) {
        }
      }
      
      ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
        Picker(selection: $shownSelected, label: Text(shownPickerLabel)) {
          }
      }
      
      ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
        Picker(selection: $guessSelected, label: Text(guessPickerLabel)) {
          }
      }
    }.padding(10)
    
    HStack {
      ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
        Button("FLIP               ") {
        }
      }
      Spacer()
      ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
        Button("NEXT               ") {
        }
      }
    }.padding(10)
    
  }
  .padding()
}
```

I would appreciate any thoughts anyone has on the matter.  The most likely scenario is that I am doing something wrong, after all I am a novice!  But maybe this is just iOS 15.6 asserting itself? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Could you test it with the same feeling as the example code?

I couldn't find a place in your code that might be a problem, but I think there's been a problem somewhere because there are so many overlap of Zstack.

[image]
[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.white)
                .overlay(Text("Pick a Topic to study below."))
                .padding(10)
            
            VStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
                    .fill(.white)
                    .overlay(Text("topicPickerLabel"))
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
                    .fill(.white)
                    .overlay(Text("shownPickerLabel"))

                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
                    .fill(.white)
                    .overlay(Text("guessPickerLabel"))
            }.padding(10)
            
            HStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
                    .fill(.white)
                    .overlay(
                        Button("FLIP               ") {}
                    )
                Spacer()
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
                    .fill(.white)
                    .overlay(
                        Button("NEXT               ") {}
                    )
            }.padding(10)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .padding()
        .background(.gray)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice("iPhone 14 Pro")
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice("iPhone SE (3rd generation)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the response!  I am going to be traveling for a bit, but I'll dig into this as soon as I get back and let you know!  Thanks again!